# Prove that $\operatorname{cond}_2(A) \le n \cdot \operatorname{cond}_2(DAD)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be positive definite with the unit diagonal. Let the matrix $D \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be diagonal positive definite. Prove that $$\operatorname{cond}_2(A) \le n\cdot \operatorname{cond}_2(DAD),$$ where $\operatorname{cond}_2(A) = \|A\|_2\|A^{-1}\|_2$.

Really I have no idea how to prove it. I can only propose several suitable inequalities such that $\|B\|_2^2 \le \|B\|_1\|B\|_\infty$, $\|DAD\|_2 \le d_{\max}^2\|A\|_2$, where $d_{\max} = \|D\|_2$ is the maximal diagonal element of $D$. And $\|D^{-1}A^{-1}D^{-1}\|_2 \le \dfrac{1}{d_{\min}}\|A^{-1}\|_2$, so $\operatorname{cond}_2(D^{-1}AD^{-1}) \le \dfrac{d_{\min}}{d_{\max}} \operatorname{cond}_2(A)$.

Great thanks for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Idea in next trick

$||A||_2 = ||DD^{-1}AD^{-1}D|| \leq ||D^{-1}||^2_2 ~||DAD||_2$
$||A^{-1}||_2 = ||DD^{-1}A^{-1}D^{-1}D|| \leq ||D||^2_2 ~||D^{-1}A^{-1}D^{-1}||_2$

also use $||A||_2 \leq ||A||_F = \sqrt{\sum|a_{ij}|^2}$, for $D: ||D||_F \leq \sqrt{n}d_{max}$

but you should deal with $d_{max}/d_{min}$, may be you can find better way :) good luck

$cond_2(A) \leq ncond_2(DAD) d^2_{max}/d^2_{min}$